# Cannot run rails new myapp -d postgresql

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, git, ruby, ruby-on-rails

I was following the tutorial here: https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10
I reached the part where I run to create my app and it starts then I run into this error:

```
      create
      create  README.md
      create  Rakefile
      create  .ruby-version
      create  config.ru
      create  .gitignore
      create  Gemfile
         run  git init from "."
error: chmod on /mnt/c/code/myapp/.git/config.lock failed: Operation not permitted
fatal: could not set 'core.filemode' to 'false'
      create  package.json
      create  app
      create  app/assets/config/manifest.js
      create  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
      create  app/channels/application_cable/channel.rb
      create  app/channels/application_cable/connection.rb
      create  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
      create  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
      create  app/javascript/channels/consumer.js
      create  app/javascript/channels/index.js
      create  app/javascript/packs/application.js
      create  app/jobs/application_job.rb
      create  app/mailers/application_mailer.rb
      create  app/models/application_record.rb
      create  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.html.erb
      create  app/views/layouts/mailer.text.erb
      create  app/assets/images/.keep
      create  app/controllers/concerns/.keep
      create  app/models/concerns/.keep
      create  bin
      create  bin/rails
      create  bin/rake
      create  bin/setup
      create  bin/yarn
Traceback (most recent call last):
        33: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `<main>'
        32: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:24:in `eval'
        31: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
        30: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin/rails:23:in `load'
        29: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/exe/rails:10:in `<top (required)>'
        28: from /home/r/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        27: from /home/r/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        26: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/cli.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        25: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
        24: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
        23: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
        22: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        21: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        20: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/commands/application/application_command.rb:26:in `perform'
        19: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
        18: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
        17: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
        16: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
        15: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
        14: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
        13: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
        12: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
        11: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:302:in `create_bin_files'
        10: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:156:in `build'
         9: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:92:in `bin'
         8: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/railties-6.0.0.rc1/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/app_generator.rb:19:in `chmod'
         7: from /home/r/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/actions/file_manipulation.rb:154:in `chmod'
         6: from /home/r/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1015:in `chmod_R'
         5: from /home/r/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1015:in `each'
         4: from /home/r/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1016:in `block in chmod_R'
         3: from /home/r/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1464:in `preorder_traverse'
         2: from /home/r/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1018:in `block (2 levels) in chmod_R'
         1: from /home/r/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1321:in `chmod'
/home/r/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/lib/ruby/2.6.0/fileutils.rb:1321:in `chmod': Operation not permitted @ apply2files - /mnt/c/code/myapp/bin (Errno::EPERM)
```

I really I'm not sure what is going on here and I'm stuck. I tried running the command "chmod +t -R ~/.bundle" but that also said that no such file or directory. I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand what is going on and to help me.